# How can I get the proper value of proper button with this method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Code:**

```
 for (int i = 1; i < butonsayisi; i++)
        {
            int buttonvalue = 1;

            var buttonmenu = new Button
            {

                HeightRequest = 100,
                WidthRequest = 100,
                Margin = 5,
                CornerRadius = 15,
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(192,192,192),

            };

        buttonmenu.Clicked += butonmenu;
        butonlar.Children.Add(buttonmenu);
            if (baglanti.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                baglanti.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand getir = new SqlCommand("select * from butonlar where id = '" + i.ToString() + "'", baglanti);
            SqlDataReader oku = getir.ExecuteReader();
            while (oku.Read())
            {
                buttonmenu.Text = oku.GetValue(1).ToString();
                baglanti.Close();
                break;
            }



            async void butonmenu(object o, EventArgs args)
            {


                baglanti.Open();
                SqlCommand getirici = new SqlCommand("select * from butonlar where id = '" + buttonvalue.ToString() + "'", baglanti);
                SqlDataReader okuyucu = getirici.ExecuteReader();
                while (okuyucu.Read())
                {
                    butonadi = okuyucu.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    baglanti.Close();
                    break;
                }
                await DisplayAlert("Alert","Deneme " + butonadi,"OK");
                buttonvalue++;

            }
        }
```

I have to reach the right `buttonvalue`.

`butonsayisi` counts how much row I have in database, this is how I create buttons and after that I edit the name of buttons with `buttonmenu.Text = oku.GetValue(1).ToString();` in index 1 I have the the name of buttons.

So in index 2 I have another table name. When I press the button, I have to get the right table name. With this method I use, I am taking another button's index 2.

```
await DisplayAlert("Alert","Deneme " + butonadi,"OK"); is just for testing.
```

Comment: If possible, please add some comments to your code block so others can understand it.  Also, the question needs some work and should probably be more specific to Xamarin forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it guys!

simply i did;

```
SqlCommand getirici = new SqlCommand("select * from butonlar where butonadi = '" + buttonmenu.Text + "'", baglanti);
                    SqlDataReader okuyucu = getirici.ExecuteReader();
                    while (okuyucu.Read())
                    {
                        butonadi = okuyucu.GetValue(2).ToString();
                        baglanti.Close();
                        break;
                    }
```

i used to get the value from id now i get from name of button so it works!

Comment: I'm glad you go it working.  I believe I suggested using the Text property of the Button to store the ID in one of your earlier questions.  I'd also suggest just querying all of the buttons once and storing them in memory rather than doing repeated queries on every click, which seems wasteful.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people .